# 2013 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2013 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: It would be good to have people who want to run describe their policy and how they would moderate as an answer to this.

Comment: should the Q&A started in the comments be answered in the comments, or should they be lumped together into one big "answer" on a different "question"?

Comment: @fredsbend There's already a place for that: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1

Comment: @svidgen lol. No one had nominated themselves yet when I made that comment. Thanks.

Comment: @warren My understanding is that there will be a special master question posted here to meta where each of us can post a single answer to a selection [of these questions](http://goo.gl/p9G5W). Also if you want somebody from the COMM team [suggested](http://goo.gl/uVyzN) nominees could use answers to this post as a venue to post an extended free form statement about their candidacy. See also [Where can a Moderator Candidate post an extended statement?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1991)